# Jquery generic structuration algorithm

Tags: jquery

im triyng to solve this problem of generic code structuration in Jquery.

I have a listener who do something when an html listbox change, just like this:

```
<script>
$("#sdate").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
            fase1: $(this).val()
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function (d) {
            $('.selector').html(d);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Some times the listbox sdate can be different, i mean, some times *sdate* could be like this:

```
<select id="sdate">
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
```

Other times could be like this:

```
<select id="sdate">
<option fase2="some_value">option1</option>
<option fase2="some_value">option2</option>
</select>
```

Depending on the aviability of the parameter fase1 the GET vars i will send via ajax will change, for example if is `<option>option1</option>` the ajax call will be:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
            fase1: $(this).val()
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function (d) {
            $('.selector').html(d);
        }
    });
```

But if the listbox is like `<option fase2="some_value">option1</option>` the ajax call have to be like:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
            fase1: THE_VALUE_FASE2_ON_THE_OPTION_PARAMETER
        },
        fase2: $(this).val()
    }, type: 'get',
    success: function (d) {
        $('.selector').html(d);
    }
    });
```

Im very new at jquery so this is making me some problems, thanks for any orientation of how to script this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't evaluate the fase2 or fase1 attribute before send?

like `$('#sdate').attr('fase1');` this return the value of attribute fase1 on your jquery.

```
<script>
$("#sdate").change(function () {
    var fase2 = $(this).attr('fase2');
    var value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {
            ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
            fase1: fase2 == '' ? value : fase_2,
        },
        type: 'get',
        success: function (d) {
            $('.selector').html(d);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Something like this ???

EDIT: i think now it s better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: If you both need fase1 and fase2 in cond 2:

```
var data = {
    ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
};
if ( $(this).attr("fase2") ) {
    data.fase1 = $(this).attr("fase2");
    data.fase2 = $(this).val();
} else {
    data.fase1 = $(this).val();
}
```

And then in the object's data variable referer to our data variable just created

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: data,
    type: 'get',
    success: function (d) {
        $('.selector').html(d);
    }
});
```

If its a matter about fase1 is the attribute or the value:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
        ref: '<?php echo $_GET['ref']; ?>',
        fase1: $(this).attr('fase2') || $(this).val()
    },
    type: 'get',
    success: function (d) {
        $('.selector').html(d);
    }
});
```